# Unable to Access Other Apps in Django

Tags: python, django, django-views

I am writing a beginner Django app.  I am currently able to the first app that I created.  However, I am not able to figure out how to access the other two apps.

```
swiss (project)
  |_ app_picker (default app)
  |_ eft
  |_ servermon
```

I am currently able to access the app_picker by typing **127.0.0.1:8000/app_picker/**.  But when I type in **127.0.0.1:8000/eft** or **172.0.0.1:8000/servermon** the page is not found.  What am I failing to understand with my Django config?

**Installed Apps**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'app_picker',
    'etf',
    'servermon',
]
```

**Project URLS**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.views.generic import RedirectView
from django.urls import include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('app_picker/', include('app_picker.urls')),
    path('etf/', include('etf.urls')),
    path('servermon/', include('servermon.urls')),
    path('', RedirectView.as_view(url='app_picker/', permanent=True)),
]

#Add Django site authentication urls (for login, logout, password management)
urlpatterns += [
    path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
]
```

**app_picker URLs**

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

**eft URLs**

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('eft/', views.base, name='eft_base'),
]
```

**eft Views**

```
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.
def base(request):
    return render(request, 'eft_base.html')
```

**servermon URLs**

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('servermon/', views.base, name='servermon_base'),
]
```

**servermon Views**

```
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.
def base(request):
    return render(request, 'servermon_base.html')
```

Answer (score 1):

In `etf.urls.py` change:

```
path('eft/', views.base, name='eft_base'),
```

To:

```
path('', views.base, name='eft_base'),
```

And then access:

```
127.0.0.1:8000/eft/
```

---

Similarly, in `servermon.urls.py` change:

```
path('servermon/', views.base, name='servermon_base'),
```

To:

```
path('', views.base, name='servermon_base'),
```

And then access:

```
127.0.0.1:8000/servermon/
```

---

**Without changing these files, if you want to access, then you need to use:**

```
127.0.0.1:8000/eft/eft/
```

Here from the url `eft/eft/`:

```
path('etf/', include('etf.urls')),
```

Matches the first `eft/` and then search continues with the remaining part `eft/` in `etf.urls.py`:

```
path('eft/', views.base, name='eft_base'),
```

Matches the remaining part `eft/` and the `views.base` is used to process the request.

---

Similarly for the other one use:

```
172.0.0.1:8000/servermon/servermon/
```

---

You might want to read: [URL dispatcher](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/urls/) and [django.urls functions for use in URLconfs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/urls/).

Answer (score 0):

It's because your path definition is not the same as your expected result.

**eft Urls** should be like this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.base, name='eft_base'),
]
```

and **servermon Urls**:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.base, name='servermon_base'),
]
```

This because when you access `172.0.0.1:8000/servermon/`, django will go to ROOT_URLS (**Project Urls**) to matching the path. Found `/servermon/`, then it will extract this part in the url and then go next to the `include('servermon.urls')`. After extracting the matched part, now it only have `''` so your servermon path should be like above.

Answer (score 0):

Did you include 'etf' and 'servermon' url in project urls.py file?

```
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
path('', include('tvapp.urls')),
path('', include('wifiapp.urls')),
```